# Trouble making searchfield on click show button and hide when it closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to show the submit button when I click on the search field and I also am trying to hide it when the field closes (the is form located in the main navigation bar)...

This is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search-click").click(function(){
    $(".search-form .search-submit").css("display" , "block");
  });
});
```

It's not working at all...this is my link : http://dev.pixstreammedia.com.s150147.gridserver.com/system/

Comment: What's not working about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5UJ5U/1/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="search" class="searchclick" placeholder="search">

    <input type="submit" class="sub" value="search">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".sub").hide();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".searchclick").click(function(){
    $(".sub").fadeToggle('fast');
  });
});
```

Comment: this is awesome thanks. Can I make it appear when people type text in the search field ?

Answer (score 0):

1.You are not showing the right id : your button has id : `search-submit-button` and you display block the other element but not this id, so the solution is  to add   `#search-submit-button` to your display block function.

2.As for the hiding you could do an mouseleave, to class: `search-form` then hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

It's working the button is just tucked underneath. Also in the console the $ isn't assigned to jQuery, so I had manually use your snippet with jQuery directly.

```
jQuery(".search-form .search-submit").css("display" , "block");
```

Type that into your js console to see the button is there, but you only see a small portion of it.